# How are simple functions done in commercial products?

Tags: microcontroller

In commercial products, here for example a Google Home or Alexa, how are simple functions implemented? Say I want to make an I/O system which uses Bluetooth but without using an Arduino. An Arduino is too powerful and expensive for turning an LED on and off. In a Google Home, it can use WiFi Bluetoooth, send data to the company etc. but apparently it is not using one on those microcontrollers that are used in our DIY or protoype projects like an Arduino or Raspberry Pi but instead some custom one.

How can I get such simple functions to work in a minimalistic way but it should professional even if the process is complicated.

I am starting out right now and if I have made any illogical statement then please forgive me.

Comment: Anything capable of Bluetooth is by itself more powerful than you need to just turn an LED on or off.

Comment: An arduino and especially a raspberry pi are *not* microcontrollers. The arduino is a dev board (and has a microcontroller on it, specifically an ATmega for most of them), and the rpi is a single-board computer.

Comment: ESP, or Nordic Semi.

Comment: Indeed, it's not likely to find a Raspberry pi or Arduino being used in commercial products. But Microcontrollers like the STM32, Atmel AVR etc. are often found in products like DC power supply, car heaters, vending machines etc. DEvelopment boards like Arduino is mainly for prototyping. However, it's not unusual to find only the ATmega328P chip with Arduino bootloader with other necessary components in a product's PCB.

Comment: There is nothing 'simple' about implementing WiFi or Bluetooth. In your Arduino which 'simply' turns an LED on & off example, 99% of the effort is used in supporting that communication channel, and 1% (or less) in implementing the LED functionality. All that communication functionality is not 'free'.

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that you're asking about commercial products like Google Home and Alexa, but you also say that an Arduino is too powerful. The microcontrollers that Google Home and Alexa use are much more powerful than the one on an Arduino. Are you asking two separate questions (namely, "how is this implemented in products like Google Home and Alexa" and "how can I implement this using something simpler than an Arduino")?

Comment: Can you clarify if your question is about a product like a Google Home Hub or similar "controller" device, or about a device which would be controlled by that hub? The requirements are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the commercial devices use considerably more powerful MCUs than hobbyist MCU modules such as Arduino.

For example, Google Home has a dual-core Cortex A7 in the form of a Marvell 88DE3006. There's also a 32-bit ARM Cortex-M0+ in there.

As a hobbyist you can use hobbyist modules such as Raspberry Pi to perform similar functions, but the cost will probably be higher. The ESP32 series of modules from Espressif provides a low-cost way for hobbyists to access Wifi and BT without having a mass produced product. You can also use the hobbyist-friendly Arduino IDE. There are also various evaluation modules if you're prototyping a product that will be made in large quantity, such as those from ST, NXP, WCH (Nanjing Qinheng Microelectronics) etc.

Just communicating over a wireless protocol such as Wifi or BT requires many thousands of lines of code for generally useful minimally functionality such as turning an LED on and off. You often don't have to write that code (there are open-source options such as lwIP, for example), but the code has to be in the memory and running on the MCU.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, as I am a beginner, it helped me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Given the current state of technology, an arduino *is* about the right "power level" to turn leds on and off.

The price of a MCU with the capability of an arduino uno is quite cheap, probably 0.1-0.5 USD in 2023. Totally reasonable for a LED project.

The reason an arduino doesn't cost that little is because of the PCB, packaging, connectors, and other misc circuits. Those aren't necessary for a production product, they're included to make the arduino easier to use for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, very low cost modules on ebay, Amazon, and Alibaba that can do simple Bluetooth functions.  They all use ICs designed specifically for this, not general purpose parts like an Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the wireless communication protocol overhead described by other answers aside, the most common way to implement logic in products these days is, in fact, is to use a microcontroller.

Yes, often they are a huge overkill for the applications, but they are extremely cheap. It takes less time and effort to write a simple program than it takes to design a logic circuit. Moreover, the modern low-end MCUs can be as cheap as $0.01/pc.

On some highly-mass-produced products, there might be custom integrated circuits (application-specific IC) as that could be cheaper when dealing with massive production numbers.